# How can I display ID column as routing hyperlink in flask app?

Tags: python, pandas, flask, url-routing

I'm very new to flask and need a step by step explanation (if possible) on how to add routing hyperlink to all my values in the ID column in my `view.html` table.

I've tried adding clickable URL to pandas column, but it doesn't seem to be working. I need to go to /templates/ids/.html from each value in the ID column in table displayed in view.html

Would someone be able to explain how this can be done step by step? Thanks for your understanding and help!

my.csv

```
date,ID,Name,Value1,Value2,Value3
01-09-2020,1,ACME,0,0,0
02-09-2020,1,ACME,0,0,0
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import *
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ids/<id>')
def landing_page(id):
    return print("Hello World" + <ID>)

@app.route("/")
def show_home():
    data = pd.read_csv("/path/my.csv", quotechar='"')
    def make_clickable(val):
    return '<a href="{{ url_for('templates', filename='ids/<ID>.html') }}">{<ID>}</a>'.format(val,val)
    data['ID'].style.format(make_clickable)
    data.set_index(['ID'], inplace=True)
    data.index.ID=None
    myId = data.loc[data.Item=='Sword']
    return render_template('view.html',tables=[myId.to_html(classes='sword')],

    titles = ['na', 'Sample title'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**view.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Project</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h1>My header</h1>
  {% for table in tables %}
    <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

desired output in view.html:

[image]

Comment: It looks very complex for what you finally want to show.
Can you please provide some example of your final result (html)? I am sure there are much simpler solutions to do this, except if you deliberately want it to be so complex

Comment: you need to put the href in your template loop. Jinja doesn't replace additional variables inside of variables (there are ways to preprocess it but it would be pointless). Follow the flask getting started to understand how Flask and Jinja work

Comment: Hi archer, I definitely aim to make it as simple as possible, but as I have very little knowledge of flask I'm probably doing this wrong... I added desired output and my.csv format. Would you be able to help with this? thanks!

Comment: Cfreak I looked at the flask docs, but I think I still need some step by step guidance if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way. Let me know if it works. One notice: change the folder of id files to static and put them there, because templates file gives an error and needs some additional work to be done

Your app.py

```
from flask import *
import pandas as pd
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/ids/<id>')
def landing_page(id):
    return print("Hello World" + <ID>)

@app.route("/")
def show_home():
    data = pd.read_csv("/path/my.csv", quotechar='"')
    return render_template('view.html', data=data, cols=data.columns)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

view.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<title>Project</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h1>My header</h1>
  <table>
    <th>
      {% for i in cols %}
      <td> {{i}} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </th>
     {% for k in range(data|length) %}
    <tr>
      <td> <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='ids/' + data.iloc[k,0]|string) }}"> {{data.iloc[k,0]}} </a> </td>
      {% for j in cols[1:]  %}
      <td> {{data.iloc[k][j]}} </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks archer! It works for me now! I just had to add `.html` in this line:  `<td> <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='ids/' + data.iloc[k,0]|string)+'.html' }}"> {{data.iloc[k,0]}} </a> </td>`

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that